# Building a 1,000M row MySQL table

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, binaryfiles, large-data

[reposted on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/317643/building-a-1-000m-row-mysql-table)

#### Questions

Question 1: as the size of the database table gets larger how can I tune MySQL to increase the speed of the LOAD DATA INFILE call?

Question 2: would using a cluster of computers to load different csv files, improve the performance or kill it? (this is my bench-marking task for tomorrow using the load data and bulk inserts)

#### Goal

We are trying out different combinations of feature detectors and clustering parameters for image search, as a result we need to be able to build and big databases in a timely fashion.

#### Machine Info

The machine has 256 gig of ram and there are another 2 machines available with the same amount of ram if there is a way to improve the creation time by distributing the database?

#### Table Schema

the table schema looks like

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| match_index   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| cluster_index | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| id            | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tfidf         | float            | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

#### Benchmarking so far

First step was to compare bulk inserts vs loading from a binary file into an empty table.

```
It took:  0:09:12.394571  to do  4,000  inserts with 5,000 rows per insert

It took:  0:03:11.368320  seconds to load 20,000,000 rows from a csv file
```

Given the difference in performance I have gone with loading the data from a binary csv file, first I loaded binary files containing 100K, 1M, 20M, 200M rows using the call below.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/mnt/tests/data.csv' INTO TABLE test;
```

I killed the 200M row binary file (~3GB csv file) load after 2 hours.

So I ran a script to create the table, and insert different numbers of rows from a binary file then drop the table, see the graph below.

[image]

It took about 7 seconds to insert 1M rows from the binary file. Next I decided to benchmark inserting 1M rows at a time to see if there was going to be a bottleneck at a particular database size. Once the Database hit approximately 59M rows the average insert time dropped to approximately 5,000/second

[image]

Setting the global key_buffer_size = 4294967296 improved the speeds slightly for inserting smaller binary files. The graph below shows the speeds for different numbers of rows

[image]

However for inserting 1M rows it didn't improve the performance.

rows:  1,000,000  time:  0:04:13.761428  inserts/sec:  3,940

vs for an empty database

rows:  1,000,000  time:  0:00:6.339295  inserts/sec:  315,492

Comment: I think that it may be worth asking this at http://Serverfault.com, since SO is programming related and you seem to look for hardcore admin experience. +1 for really doing your homework so far though, excellent question.